# How to find the value of x when you know y

Tags: python, numpy

I have the code down below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sigma=0.34 #[nm]
epsilum=2.844 #[mev]

def energy(a):
    return 2*epsilum*(3.009028595*(sigma/a)**12-3.305692649*(sigma/a)**6)

a_list=np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)
plt.plot(a_list, energy(a_list))
plt.xlim([-0.01,0.01])

print(np.min(energy(a_list)))
```

I found the minimum value of energy, but i want to find for which value of a we have the minimum energy.
Is there any specific way to do that?

I want to find a way to calculate the value of a corresponding to the minimum energy

Comment: Numpy `argmin` would return the index of the minimum value. If you could get the index of your minimum value in `energy(a_list)` you can use the same index to find the corresponding x in `a_list`. TL;DR: what you are looking for must be: `a_list[np.argmin(energy(a_list))]`

Answer (score 2):

```
min_index = np.argmin(energy(a_list))
a_min = a_list[min_index]
print("The value of a corresponding to the minimum energy is:", a_min)
```

Output:

-5.164000434267866

The value of a corresponding to the minimum energy is: -0.37537537537537535

https://trinket.io/python3/3b3ef88ed1